# what are (some of the) UTF8 string functions in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, unicode

For dealing with ASCII we have strlen, strcat etc..
For UTF16(i.e, UCS2) we have `wcscat` and `wcslen` functions.

For dealing with UTF8 and UCS4 what are the functions available in C?
Assume Linux/gcc

Comment: On POSIX OSs `wchar_t` is usually 4 bytes wide and thus represents UCS4. And: UTF16 is /more/ than UCS2. What exactly is the behaviour you want? The number of glyphs or the number of code-points?

Comment: I am trying to understand different encodings for Unicode. whcar_t is used to represent USC2 in Windows and USC4 in Linux (whchar_t is 2 bytes in windows and 4 bytes in linux). wchar_cannot be used for UFT8/UTF16 - Am i right ?

Comment: Well, of course it /can/ be used (at least for UTF16 on Windows). But you won't get sensible data from `wcslen` et al. IMHO you better stay away from `wchar_t` for everything that has to be portable and use `std::string` with UTF8 helper functions internally. But this depends highly on your usecase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think standard C libraries have UTF-8 functions. There are surely libraries for it.

However, normal str functions can be used with UTF-8 in many cases.
`strlen` works well, returning the number of bytes (not characters).
`strcat` works (it also overruns your buffer easily, but this is normal for strcat).

The reason is that the 0 character can't appear in multi-byte UTF-8 data. So if it appears in a UTF-8 string, it's surely its end, just like in ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

The standard does not specify the encoding or size used for the wide character functions, so assuming it to be UCS2, UCS4 or anything else is not portable. C11 brings standardized unicode support, but I think it's to early to rely on that being implemented yet. Your best bet is to find a library to handle conversion to/from UTF8/UCS4 or any other encoding you may need.

Have a look at [iconv](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/iconv.3.html), or the chapter on [character handling](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Character-Handling.html#Character-Handling) in the GNU C library manual.